# Transpose (maybe) rows to columns

Tags: sql-server

```
Employee    Entity      Payor           Location    PROC_QTY    Work_RVUs   CHARGES  PAYMENTS   REFUNDS UPL_DISTRIBUTION
No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1     Inpatient   679.5        3.45        84423.5 14514.85   0               0
```

I need a way to convert the above to the below in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Employee    Entity      Payor       Location    Account     Amount
No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   PROC_QTY    679.5

No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   Work_RVUs   3.45

No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   CHARGES     84423.5

No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   PAYMENTS    14514.85

No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   REFUNDS      0

No Employee 29040100    BCBS - FSC1 Inpatient   UPL_DISTRIBUTION    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`unpivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx):

> **Unpivot Transformation**
>   
>  The Unpivot transformation makes an unnormalized dataset into a more normalized version by expanding values from multiple columns in a single record into multiple records with the same values in a single column.

Here's a sample ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62385/2/0)):

```
select
 p.*
from MyTable as t
unpivot
(
    Amount for Account in 
    (
         PROC_QTY
        ,Work_RVUs
        ,CHARGES
        ,PAYMENTS
        ,REFUNDS
        ,UPL_DISTRIBUTION
    )
) as p
```

Note where I've specified `Amount`(value) and `Account`(column name).